# Insert dynamic WHERE condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to dynamically search for results inside table. That is why I've created `@MEST_CDO_SEARCH` variable. This variable looks like part of the query, after it is dynamically filled with results:

```
DECLARE @MEST_CDO_SEARCH NVARCHAR(MAX);


SELECT @MEST_CDO_SEARCH = STUFF((SELECT 'OR MEST.MEST_CDO LIKE ''%' + _MEST_CDO2 + '%'' '
FROM @tblEAN128
FOR xml path('')),1,3,'')
```

After this `@MEST_CDO_SEARCH` looks like this:

> > @MEST_CDO_SEARCH :
>
> ```
> MEST.MEST_CDO LIKE '%QzYyOUhNIE1L%' OR MEST.MEST_CDO LIKE '%Uks3MkNOIE1L%'
> ```

Query for searching is like this (just part of the query inside `WHERE` condition):

```
(@xmlMEST_CDO2 IS NULL OR @xmlMEST_CDO2 IS NOT NULL AND MEST.MEST_CDO LIKE '%' + (SELECT EAN128._MEST_CDO2 FROM @tblEAN128 EAN128) + '%')
```

Last part of this query:

```
MEST.MEST_CDO LIKE '%' + (SELECT EAN128._MEST_CDO2 FROM @tblEAN128 EAN128) + '%'
```

must be dynamic. But I don't know how to insert `@MEST_CDO_SEARCH` ? I would like `WHERE` to look like this:

```
    (@xmlMEST_CDO2 IS NULL OR @xmlMEST_CDO2 IS NOT NULL 
AND MEST.MEST_CDO LIKE '%QzYyOUhNIE1L%' OR MEST.MEST_CDO LIKE '%Uks3MkNOIE1L%')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use dynamic SQL like this:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)

SET @sql = 'SELECT * .............(your query)..........' + 
            'WHERE (@xmlMEST_CDO2 IS NULL OR @xmlMEST_CDO2 IS NOT NULL AND ('+@MEST_CDO_SEARCH+'))'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```